# Ansible keeps on creating multiple API Gateway on every execution

Tags: ansible, aws-api-gateway

This is my plabook content to create and deploy AWS API Gateway. Somehow Ansible keeps on creating duplicate API Gateways on every execution and i am not sure how to control this.

```
    - name: deploy API Gateway
      tags: deploy
      aws_api_gateway:
        state: present
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        swagger_file: swagger.yml
        stage: test
        deploy_desc: test deployment
      register: api_result

    - debug: 
            var: api_result

    - name: test api gateway endpoint
      uri:
        url: https://{{ api_result.api_id }}.execute-api.{{ aws_region }}.amazonaws.com/test
        return_content: yes
      register: webpage

    - debug: 
            var: webpage
```

This is my Swagger file:

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "2018-05-10T07:51:38Z"
  title: "MyAPI"
  description: "REST API"
host: "rijjh41w9e.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
basePath: "/test"
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  /:
    get:
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:ap-south-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:174336093897:function:MyLambda/invocations"
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
        type: "aws"
definitions:
  Empty:
    type: "object"
    title: "Empty Schema"
```

Please help me to restrict Ansible so that it shouldn't create duplicate API Gateways on every execution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, According to [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/aws_api_gateway_module.html) it's not supported yet (Always create)
You can write a new module that list current api gateways (get the relevant id by name) and delete (By api_id) before you create another one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Koby Ben Mordechai said

> Well, According to documentation it's not supported yet (Always create) You can write a new module that list current api gateways (get the relevant id by name) and delete (By api_id) before you create another one.

Today (~ summer 2019), [aws_api_gateway](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_api_gateway_module.html) is creating a new endpoint if `api_id` is not defined ; update it otherwise (if exist, you are owner, ...).

The problem is to **retrieve an existing endpoint by its name**.

Could be done by a `library/aws_api_gateway_get_id.py` [ansible custom module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html) (inspired from original [aws_api_gateway](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/aws_api_gateway.py)):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
__metaclass__ = type

import json

try:
    import botocore
except ImportError:
    # HAS_BOTOCORE taken care of in AnsibleAWSModule
    pass

import traceback
from ansible.module_utils.aws.core import AnsibleAWSModule
from ansible.module_utils.ec2 import (AWSRetry, camel_dict_to_snake_dict)
from itertools import ifilter


def main():
    argument_spec = dict(
        name=dict(type='str', required=True),
    )

    module = AnsibleAWSModule(
        argument_spec=argument_spec,
        supports_check_mode=False,
    )

    name = module.params.get('name')

    client = module.client('apigateway')

    api_id = get_api_id(client, name)

    exit_args = {"api_id": api_id, "name" : name}

    module.exit_json(**exit_args)


retry_params = {"tries": 10, "delay": 5, "backoff": 1.2}


@AWSRetry.backoff(**retry_params)
def get_api_id(client, name):
    items = client.get_rest_apis()['items']
    for api_elem in ifilter(lambda x: x['name'] in [ name ], items):
        return api_elem['id']
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usage in your ansible Playbook:

```
  - name: Get AWS API Gateway id if exist
    aws_api_gateway_get_id:
      name: the-api-endpoint-name
    register: aws_api_gateway_get_id_result
  - name: Deploying API endpoint
    aws_api_gateway:
      api_id: '{{ aws_api_gateway_get_id_result.api_id | default(omit, true) }}'
      stage: default
      swagger_text: '{{ lookup(''template'', ''swagger.yml.j2'') }}'
```